# Expression for "let's use this opportunity"?

Tags: expressions

What expression can I use to indicate that I see an opportunity and suggest an action?

I'm thinking of trivial situations.

> "Wife, I'm going to the post office."
>
> "The baker shop is nearby. *Use this as an opportunity* to buy some bread.

---

> "Boss, we're placing an order to upgrade the office's computers."
>
> "*Use this as an opportunity* to replace our old printer."

---

> "I went to the gym's desk to renew my membership and I've *used this as an opportunity* to enroll my son in Judo classes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

> "The baker shop is nearby. Use this as an opportunity to buy some bread.

`"While we're around let's pick up some bread."`

> "Boss, we're placing an order to upgrade the office's computers."

`"While we're at it let's replace the old printer"`

Finally,

`"I went to the gym's desk to renew my membership and since I was already there I went ahead and enrolled my son in Judo classes"`